# trouble with adding Spinner in CSipSimple

Tags: android, web-services, csip-simple

I'm trying to add spinner in my CSipSimple account registration form. but i'm having error at few lines.
first i'm having error at

> accountUserName = (Spinner) findViewById("username");

findViewById is undefined.
Second is at

> ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);

saying Constructor ArrayAdapter is undefined.
this code was working fine in a saperate program but when i tried to put this code in CSipsimple Basic.java file it showed these two errors. can someone please help me?

```
public class Basic extends BaseImplementation {
protected static final String THIS_FILE = "Basic W";    

InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;
JSONObject json = null;

private Spinner accountUserName;
private EditTextPreference accountDisplayName;
//private EditTextPreference accountUserName;
private EditTextPreference accountServer;
private EditTextPreference accountPassword;

private void bindFields() {
accountDisplayName = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("display_name");
accountUserName = (Spinner) findViewById("username");
accountServer = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("server");
accountPassword = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("password");
}

public void fillLayout(final SipProfile account) {
bindFields();

accountDisplayName.setText(account.display_name);

//fetching values fro mysql database 

String serverFull = account.reg_uri;
if (serverFull == null) {
serverFull = "";
}else {
serverFull = serverFull.replaceFirst("sip:", "");
}

ParsedSipContactInfos parsedInfo = SipUri.parseSipContact(account.acc_id);
//accountUserName.setText(parsedInfo.userName);

try
{

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.xx.xxx/conIds.php");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();

Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

try
{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
sb.append(line + "\n");
}

is.close();
result = sb.toString();

System.out.println(result);
Log.e("Pass 2", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}
//
try
{
JSONArray NJA=new JSONArray(result);
String arr=NJA.getString(1);
Log.d("My arry", ""+arr);
JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(arr);

final String[] str2 = new String[JA.length()];
for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
{

str2[i] = JA.getString(i);
}

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
{
list.add(str2[i]);

}

Collections.sort(list);

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
accountUserName.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

accountUserName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String Item=accountUserName.getSelectedItem().toString();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
}
catch(Exception e)
{

Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}

accountServer.setText(serverFull);
accountPassword.setText(account.data);
}
```

Comment: You're forgetting layouts.

Comment: can you please explain a little more.

Comment: First define you view with numeric id.Change this findViewById("username")

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `android.app.Activity` (in which `findViewById(int)` is defined) and `android.widget.ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: android.widget.ArrayAdapter is added but error is still there and even after adding '"android.app.Activity"' findViewById is underline. and i think error is due to keyword "this" i tried to replace it with class name but it's still causing error.

Comment: and `ClassName.class`?